# Trigger an event when search box is cleared

Tags: javascript

I'm making a dynamic search box that filters as you type.
The issue is when the box is cleared, the pagination does not reset itself.
Is there a way to trigger an event (call some functions) when the box is being cleared by the user?

I tried this:

```
document.addEventListener( "keyup", showStudents(number));
```

Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/Delano83/pen/RGqWja?editors=0010

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You've written all that code, with all those event handlers, and suddenly you do `document.addEventListener( "keyup", showStudents(number));` instead of `document.addEventListener( "keyup", showStudents);` =

Comment: Thanks adeneo! That helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
searchbox.addEventListener( "keyup", function(){
    if(this.value === ""){
        // box is empty,
        // call some functions
    }
});
```